# Ttrying to loop until user types in "Stop"

Tags: java

I try to do a loop that reads and processes sentences and ends only when user types "Stop" to end the program. Below is the code im using and i keep getting a compile error `else if`

```
System.out.println("Please Input a sentence and (terminate with \"STOP \")"); 

    String sentenceInput; 
    int sentenceLength; 
    char sentencePunct; 
    int divisionNum; 
    int number; 
    int divided; 
    int remainder; 

    sentenceInput= myScanner.nextLine(); 
    sentenceLength = sentenceInput.length(); 
    remainder = sentenceLength%2; 
    sentencePunct = sentenceInput.charAt(sentenceLength -1); 

    while (!sentenceInput.equals ("STOP")) {
        if (sentencePunct == '?') 
        { 
            if (remainder == 0) 
                System.out.println("Yes");`
                System.out.println("Please Input another sentence (terminate with \"STOP \")");
                sentenceInput= myScanner.nextLine(); 
            else 
                System.out.println("No");
                System.out.println("Please Input another sentence (terminate with \"STOP \")");
                sentenceInput= myScanner.nextLine(); 
        } 
        else if (sentencePunct == '!') 
                System.out.println("Wow!");
                System.out.println("Please Input another sentence (terminate with \"STOP \")");
                sentenceInput= myScanner.nextLine(); 
            else 
                System.out.println("You always say " + sentenceInput);
                System.out.println("Please Input another sentence (terminate with \"STOP \")");
                sentenceInput= myScanner.nextLine(); 
        }   

}
```

Comment: Can you post the compiler error?

Comment: i have resolved the issue, thanks compile error was 'else without if'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your scope is screwed up all over the place, need to make sure the complete if/else is enclosed with {}, as it is most of your else's don't have anything to connect to.

```
    while (!sentenceInput.equals ("STOP")) {
    if (sentencePunct == '?') 
    { 
        if (remainder == 0) {
            System.out.println("Yes");`
            System.out.println("Please Input another sentence (terminate with \"STOP \")");
            sentenceInput= myScanner.nextLine(); 
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("No");
            System.out.println("Please Input another sentence (terminate with \"STOP \")");
            sentenceInput= myScanner.nextLine(); 
        }
    } 
    else if (sentencePunct == '!') {
            System.out.println("Wow!");
            System.out.println("Please Input another sentence (terminate with \"STOP \")");
            sentenceInput= myScanner.nextLine(); 
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("You always say " + sentenceInput);
            System.out.println("Please Input another sentence (terminate with \"STOP \")");
            sentenceInput= myScanner.nextLine(); 
        }
    }
```

}

Comment: Thanks for the edit.Can i accomplish the same scope using `case` statements?

Comment: yes, but since it'll require nested switch-case, not sure whether it's worth it - doesn't look elegant, not any more simple, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You need to define the scope of statements (multiple statements) within else if and else part which you could do with braces. So your code should be:

```
else if (sentencePunct == '!')  {
    ....
} else {
    ...
}
```

if you dont define scope, then compiler just considers immediate statement after if/else/else if within scope and in your case, it would not be able to find which if to associate (last) else with.